# How to implement JQGrid paging with bulk pages?

Tags: jqgrid

I want to implement paging with bulk paging.

e.g. Say I have 950 records in DB and paging is 10 then I want to fetch data in multiple of five pages.

i.e. if I am at page 1 I should be receiving 5(50 records) pages from DB and cache them locally. So if

the user clicks on next then he/she should get data from local cache but if the user clicks  for the

sixth page then again do server request and get next 5 pages data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any easy way to implement the behavior which you asked.

I find 950 records are not too many. I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true` option. The server have to return **all rows** of data. The data need be just sorted initially. You don't need to fill `page`, `total` and `records` part of the answer. The answer could be just array of items which one typically place to `rows` part of the response. You should don't forget to use `gridview: true` option to have better performance.

Just try to use `loadonce: true` option and I hope you will have very good performance in the grid.

Comment: it was just an example. In Live there are millions of records :)

Comment: I there **large** difference between **950** records which you posted in the question and **millions** of records. The implementation should be absolutely different. For understanding: making an auto with max speed 50 km/hour is absolutely another problem as making an auto with max speed 500 km/hour. One *have to use different technologies* for making those two autos.